# Is there a proper way to stop ECS tasks and the EC2 instances inside a cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb, aws-auto-scaling

I have 2 ECS clusters in one aws account and planning to shut down 1 of the clusters, the services inside that cluster as well as stop/terminate the ec2 instances in the auto-scaling group. Is there a proper way to achieve this without leaving any traces? I have thought about the following:

1. Changing number of tasks to 0 in each ECS service (cumbersome as I have 7-8 services)
2. Setting Desired Count in auto scaling group to 0 (Not sure if this will stop or terminate the EC2 instances)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: "this without leaving any traces" what traces? Your AWS API calls?

Comment: No not the api calls, I meant all the ECS services and EC2 instances associated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using AWS Cloudformation to setup the ecs cluster, you can delete the cloudformation stack, that will remove all the resources with respect to that CF stack.

Else, see if this helps - deleting via console : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/delete_cluster.html

Comment: Yes CF was used but I have another ECS cluster in the same vpc. Will deleting the CF stack also delete the resources like vpc etc? This is not an intended action. I still need other resources in the vpc

Comment: No it shouldn't delete the VPC until and unless you are using the same cloudformation template to create a VPC. In case you are using the same cloudformation template, then update the template by removing the non-required resources. Once it is done, you can upload this template and only the non-required resources would be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you delete ECS cluster it will delete auto-scalling configuration, which also delete instances managed by autoscalling.

> [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/asg-capacity-providers-delete-capacity-provider.html#:~:text=Option%201%3A%20Use%20the%20delete%20command%20to%20delete%20the%20cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/asg-capacity-providers-delete-capacity-provider.html#:%7E:text=Option%201%3A%20Use%20the%20delete%20command%20to%20delete%20the%20cluster).

Comment: The problem is I have another ECS cluster in the same vpc which should not be affected. If I delete the cluster, will it also terminate everything created using  cloudformation?

Comment: No, it will not affected. Nothing will affected which created by cloudformation until you trigger drifts and apply changes on cfn for current cluster